# How to reduce gap between select and options list

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using basic select from mui and modified the height of the select.
After which there is gap between select and the dropdown list.

How to reduce this height?

I tried to fix it overriding .MuiPaper-root

```
<Select
          // labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          // label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
          sx={{
            minWidth: "300px",
            height: "30px",
            "& .MuiPaper-root": { // this has no effect on bringing the options list closer to the <select>
              top: "10px"
            }
          }}
```

[image]

above fix not working.

Here is code for the same
https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-basic-select-4rdq61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the padding of `.MuiSelect-select` is what made the options list shift down, you can reduce the gap by changing the padding of the select box

```
<Select
  // labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
  id="demo-simple-select"
  value={age}
  // label="Age"
  onChange={handleChange}
  sx={{
    minWidth: "300px",
    height: "30px",

    "& .MuiSelect-select": {
      padding: "0px 14px"
    }
  }}
>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-basic-select-forked-c6rwdi